# How to get Doxygen highlight the clicked method

Tags: c++, html, css, doxygen

When a method is clicked from the index, it goes to the detailed documentation of the method. However if the method happens to be near the bottom of the page, it is not visually easy to spot the documentation of the interested function. Python docs makes it easier by highlighting the clicked link's header in yellow: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#string.upper. Is it possible to achieve similar highlighting in doxygen created docs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `Doxyfile`, set:

```
HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET  = extra.css
```

Inside `extra.css` add:

```
a:target+div div:first-child {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #fbe54e;
}
```

Here is what it looks like when you click on a method:

[image: Selected method with highlighted header]

Comment: I know it's not the done thing to say 'thanks' in SO comments, but it is a real pleasure to see a relative newcomer giving a perfectly on-topic, accurate, concise and complete answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems unsupported - you should file a request to the wish list

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you could try to modify the .css file.

[How to customize Doxygen HTML Output](http://cs.swan.ac.uk/~csoliver/ok-sat-library/internet_html/doc/doc/Doxygen/1.7.6.1/html/customize.html)

[Css Highlight](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001391.htm)